# How to promote a site in a limited region in the short-term, while preparing to broaden in the long-term?

Tags: seo, pagerank, local-seo, marketing, google-local-search

Say you have a site for a brand you want to promote in one region to begin with, but you want to be able to scale it up later as you expand into other markets over time. It could be a business offering some on-site service, in one language, for example. The point is, for whatever reason, resources need to be directed at promoting and growing in one region first.

In the beginning you won't want site traffic from markets you aren't catering to. Those visitors won't find your content relevant to them anyway, and will probably bounce quickly. (I imagine the resulting high bounce rate would not impress Google PageRank.)

However, if all goes well you want to eventually grow the brand in other regions / markets too. Optimizing locally could have benefits initially, but may complicate expansion later if not planned for and scaled appropriately. There are also considerations of internationalization and localization to keep in mind.

In such a scenario, what are the factors to consider when branding and establishing an SEO strategy?

<sub>Or is it better to just spam the world and see what sticks? :)</sub>